# Giving Each List item Different name in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, json.net

I have one root class and subclass for JSON creation in my .NET API.

```
 public class Root
{

    public FT1  FT1 { get; set; }

    public Root()
    {

        this.FT1 = new FT1();

    }
}
public class FT1
{
    public List<FT11> FT1_1 { get; set; }
     public FT1()
    {
        this.FT1_1 = new List<FT11>();
    }
}
```

when i am using Newtonsoft to Serialize Root the out put will be like this

```
"FT1": {
        "FT1_1": [],

        "FT1_1": []

        "FT1_1": []

    }
```

Is there anyway i can get the result like each node have different name as following. Since the list items will be dynamic each time number of nodes will be changing  so more than 3 also possible

```
  "FT1":{
        "FT1_1": [],

        "FT1_2": [],

        "FT1_3": []

    }
```

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`.

Comment: What is `FT11`?

Comment: FT11 is an another object for inside element FT_1. That will be fine. I wanted to change only FT_1 name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace FT1 with Dictionary<string, FT11> like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public FT1 Dictionary<string, FT11> { get; set; }
}
```